# Clear the form after submit angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hi i want to clear the form values after successfull completion. Houw should i implemnt

```
<div ng-controller="employeelistController as listControl">
        <div class="container form-group" ng-controller="addEmployee as addemp">
            <form name="frmEmployee" ng-submit="Add(addemp.employee) && frmEmpbloyee.$valid">
                <div class="col-lg-4 ctrmain">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <strong>Employee No</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="number" id="txtEmpId" ng-model="addemp.employee.employeeid" required class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <strong>FirstName</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" id="txtfirstName" ng-model="addemp.employee.firstname" required class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <strong>LastName</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" id="txtlastName" ng-model="addemp.employee.lastname" required class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <strong>Department</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" id="txtDept" ng-model="addemp.employee.department" required class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <strong>DOB</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="date" id="DTdob" ng-model="addemp.employee.dateofbirth" required class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary value=" save" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

which is the best way to implement this. I have tried many ways. please help.

```
$scope.Add = function (emp,$scope) {

        this.EmployeeObject = angular.copy(emp);
        employee.push(this.EmployeeObject);
        $scope.emp = null;
    }
```

which is the best way to implement this. I have tried many ways. please help.

Comment: do addemp.employee={}

Comment: or, $scope.emp = { }. The object you are binding to ng-model, make it as { }

Comment: Try: emp = undefined;

Comment: squiroid's answer looks fine, if it's not working you have other issues. In the $scope.Add function you provide, you are setting $scope.emp = null while your model is addemp.employee ... so maybe you should $scope.addemp.employee = null or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you don't need $scope in the argument of the Add function.

```
  $scope.Add = function (emp) {     
    this.EmployeeObject = angular.copy(emp);
    employees.push(this.EmployeeObject);
    this.employee=null;
    $scope.$setPristine(true);
}
```

Comment: its not working. may be the code is correct, but for my case its not binding with the model

Comment: Here is the updated plunker:-
http://plnkr.co/edit/bMyW8zgLKBw1sldxNlDc?p=preview

Comment: You just need  this.employee=null;
        $scope.$setPristine(true); after pushing data I m updating the answer as per your question

Answer (score 1):

update it with  the demo

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  'use strict';

  
      $scope.empList = [];
    $scope.addemp = {};
    $scope.saveEmp = function(){
      $scope.empList.push($scope.addemp);
      $scope.reset();
    };
    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.addemp = {};
      $scope.form.$setPristine();
    }
});
```

```css
input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
          background-color: #FA787E;
        }
        input.ng-valid.ng-dirty {
          background-color: #78FA89;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <form name="form" id="form" novalidate ng-submit="saveEmp()">
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <strong>Employee No</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="number" id="txtEmpId" ng-model="addemp.employeeid" required class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <strong>FirstName</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" id="txtfirstName" ng-model="addemp.firstname" required class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <strong>LastName</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" id="txtlastName" ng-model="addemp.lastname" required class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <strong>Department</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" id="txtDept" ng-model="addemp.department" required class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <strong>DOB</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="date" id="DTdob" ng-model="addemp.dateofbirth" required class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid ">submit</button>
        <button type="reset" ng-disabled="form.$pristine" ng-click="reset()">reset</button>
    </div>
        </form>
        <p>form: {{addemp | json}}</p>
        <p>empList: {{empList | json}}</p>
        <p>Pristine: {{form.$pristine}}</p>
        <p> <pre>Errors: {{form.$error | json}}</pre>

        </p>
    </div></div>
```

```
$scope.Add = function (emp) {
                this.EmployeeObject = angular.copy(emp);
                employee.push(this.EmployeeObject);
                $scope.emp = {}; // initialize the form to empty object 
                $scope.frmEmployee.$setPristine(); // set it to as user has not interacted with the form.
            }
```

Comment: its not working. may be the code is correct, but for my case its not binding with the model

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared textbox with below code. e.g I have cleared FirstName textbox.

**HTML SECTION**

```
<td ng-show="a">
 <input type="text" ng-model="e.FirstName" />
</td>
```

**Controller SECTION**

```
e.FirstName= "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  'use strict';
function resetform() {
document.getElementById("frmEmployee").reset();
}
$scope.Add = function (emp,$scope) {
        this.EmployeeObject = angular.copy(emp);
        employee.push(this.EmployeeObject);
        resetform();
    }
});
```

Comment: Current accepted answer seems to fulfill the OP's need. What does your answer brings more? Also, you shall always explain the code you post as answer.

Comment: The resetform() function reset the all form fields. It is able to access the form using the id frmEmployee. This resetform()  is called after submitting data

Comment: Well, I admit your solution is different and works too. So, could you just edit your answer and pin point the difference. Mostly, adding text explaining your solution. This is just to ameliorate the way you answer and wasn't in any sense discarding your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Its pure JavaScript with simple one line code.**

```
document.getElementById('yourFormId').reset()
```

> Add this syntax at the end of the function in controller after submitting the form.