# how to reset all HTML input fields after closing angular modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I will enter username and password in text field but I will not save. Without saving that data i will close the popup modal.

When I click outside of the modal, it will close.

If I open the popup again, the previous datas are still appearing. I need to clear those datas and want to make the field as empty.

Please check the following link. [Plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/As959V/)

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.user = {
        user: 'name',
        password: null,
        notes: null
    };

    $scope.open = function () {

        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html', // loads the template
            backdrop: true, // setting backdrop allows us to close the modal window on clicking outside the modal window
            windowClass: 'modal', // windowClass - additional CSS class(es) to be added to a modal window template
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
                $scope.user = user;
                $scope.submit = function () {
                    $log.log('Submiting user info.'); // kinda console logs this statement
                    $log.log(user); 
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); // dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason
                }
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); 
                };
            },
            resolve: {
                user: function () {
                    return $scope.user;
                }
            }
        });//end of modal.open
    }; // end of scope.open function
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label>User name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
            <label>Add some notes</label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="user.notes">

</textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
              <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
          </div>
        </form>
    </script>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: assign the values to an empty string when you open the modal

Comment: I tried. Some Dropdowns are there. I made it Empty array and text fileds are empty string. But it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you are actually binding the `$scope.user` in modal to the `$scope.user` from the `ModalDemoCtrl`. To solve this, you should make a copy of your `user` before using it in the modal controller:

```
$modal.open({
     ...
     controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
         $scope.user = angular.copy(user);
         ...
     }
});
```

See [Angular.copy()](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/api/ng/function/angular.copy) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

see [Clear the form after submit angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271303/clear-the-form-after-submit-angularjs) for how to clear the form. you can trigger this in your submit function before the modal closes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with ui bootstrap promise:

```
$scope.modal.result.then(function(result) {
    console.log('client: resolved: ' + result);
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log('client: rejected: ' + reason);
});
```

I had run your code and it worked fine.

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.user = {
        user: 'name',
        password: null,
        notes: null
    };

    $scope.open = function () {

        var $theModal = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html', // loads the template
            backdrop: true, // setting backdrop allows us to close the modal window on clicking outside the modal window
            windowClass: 'modal', // windowClass - additional CSS class(es) to be added to a modal window template
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
                $scope.user = user;
                $scope.submit = function () {
                    $log.log('Submiting user info.'); // kinda console logs this statement
                    $log.log(user); 
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); // dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason
                }
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); 
                };
            },
            resolve: {
                user: function () {
                    return $scope.user;
                }
            }
        });//end of modal.open

        $theModal.result.then(function(result) {
            console.log('client: resolved: ' + result);
        }, function(reason) {
            $scope.user = {}
            console.log('client: reject: ' + reason);
        })
    }; // end of scope.open function
};
```